# Liquid - Can you have a key with another key inside it.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, liquid

Say you have a hash of  `{'name' => 'tobi', 'show-name' => 'This is {{name}}' }`

and the template is `"guess who this is? {{show-name}}"`

I want the output to be `guess who this is? This is tobi`

But it is `"guess who this is? {{show-name}}"`

That is just a simple example. But I need it for links e.g.

```
{'guide' => 'racing', 'guide-link' => '<a href='/guides/{{guide}}'>{{guide}}</a>' }`
```

template: `{{guide-link}}`

output I want: `<a href='/guides/racing'>racing</a>`

outputs I get `<a href='/guides/{{guide}}'>{{guide}}</a>`

Can this be done with Liquid? I guess you might call it nesting the keys or values of the hash.

Note: I'm using the liquid gem on ruby on rails incase that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a Hash, why not just store the values in a string and output that?

Essentially, instead of have something like

```
foo = { 
        'guide' => 'racing', 
        'guide-link' => '<a href='/guides/{{guide}}'>{{guide}}</a>' 
      }
```

You could just use a string variable like so.

```
guide = 'racing'
foo = "<a href='/guides/#{guide}'>#{guide}</a>"
```

The `#{guide}` syntax is the equivalent of

```
foo = "<a href='/guides/" + guide.to_s + "'>" + guide.to_s + "</a>"
```

However, instead of constructing your own link, it sounds like you should be using one of the link helpers that would be generated for your models. At the very least, take advantage of [`link_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to).

Comment: So `#{guide}` accesses a local `guide` ruby variable on the page? And I cant use `link_to` in this case unfortunately.

Comment: Just tested it but have one problem. It works when I manually make the hash in the controller with the local variable in the controller but if I have the hash pulled from the DB where do I put the local variable? Is it still in the controller?

Comment: If you need to access data set in a controller from a view, do what you normally would. Use a class variable. Any variable that starts with `@` should be accessible from your views.

Comment: Thanks. I have one question say `guide = name` if I enter `#{guide}`. it comes out as `{name}`, if I remove the curly brackets it comes out as `name` (which is preferable). Should it be leaving out the curly brackets, and is there harm in leaving them out and having it as just `#guide`?